# Create d3.js graph from data on mongodb server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, d3.js

How can I create d3.js graph from data on mongodb server using node.js?

Comment: there is nothing like d3 takes data from array or json...you can provide the same from an ajax. The ajax will get data from mongo DB.

Comment: I meant that is how I have done it in the past and I do not know of other ways than these. Can you give me an example please. I haven't really used ajax.

Comment: Plus node.js can be used too. That's what! I don't know how to. If you could please help me in this area!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D3.js includes ways to [request non-local data](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Requests) either as json or text (csv) via urls and such.

In a setup that is not security sensitive (like local development or a demo environment) you could fairly directly use the [mongo rest api](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-api) if you enable it, which will give you json output for objects.

Or you could write build a simple http server (like in [python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html), [perl](http://search.cpan.org/~bps/HTTP-Server-Simple-0.51/lib/HTTP/Server/Simple.pm) or [go](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/)) that execs ([python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) (also [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)), [perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) (also [backticks and `qx{}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)), [go](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/)) the `mongoexport` tool with the right parameters to [provide csv output](http://thediscoblog.com/blog/2013/06/07/mongodb-to-csv/) from mongo.

If you already have data in Mongo, and you've got Node already setup, then maybe that's what you want to use:

## [image: MongoDB®] ⇒ [image: Node.js®] ⇒ [image: Ds.js®]

If so, there's [someone out there](https://anmolkoul.wordpress.com/2015/06/05/interactive-data-visualization-using-d3-js-dc-js-nodejs-and-mongodb/) that's used Node.js® with some npm modules for MongoDB® to specifically drive a D3.js® visualization.

Comment: This helps! Although, I haven't used node.js before. I am looking forward for some help on the same. I have edited my question according to your answer though :)