# Create a gantt chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is the kind of data that I have:

```
[
  {'TotalTime': 10, 'Hour': 0, 'Name': 'Sam'}, 
  {'TotalTime': 15, 'Hour': 1, 'Name': 'Bob'}, 
  {'TotalTime': 300, 'Hour': 2, 'Name': 'Tom'},
  ... and so on till, 
  {'TotalTime': 124, 'Hour': 23, 'Name': 'Jon'}
]
```

Data for every hour of the day. And I wish to create a Gantt Chart from it where size of bars is based on TotalTime.

Names on the y axis and Hour on the x.

Is it possible to make a Gantt chart without start time and end time on d3.js?

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5538271

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, but you'd need to draw it yourself if you're using D3.js. So If you've made bar charts before, along those lines, setup some axes, add them to an SVG and use them to convert the data into rectangles you'll put on the chart, then label the rects with the names from the data. D3.js does not include a layout for this. If you haven't done so already, go through the [tutorials](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Tutorials): [Let’s Make a Bar Chart, Parts I](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/), [II](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2/) & [III](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/), then move on to looking at a [custom time axis example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176), and the [related](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes) [A](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/API-Reference)[P](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Time-Scales)[I](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting)s.

There are many other libraries that build on D3.js, like [C3](http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html) that provide prefab charts (like D3's layouts) but I'm not aware of one that does gantt style charts. There is [one example Gantt chart](http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5538271) out there (that randomly adds tasks into various scaled time views from 1 hour to 1 week) but I found it more confusing than my own time blocks below. YMMV.

I made a more calendar looking chart with d3js that you can read through here: [https://github.com/dlamblin/timeblocks](https://github.com/dlamblin/timeblocks/blob/master/timeblocks_manual_20160203.html). You've got different input data formatting, but you could adapt this in a pinch and swap axes for the rotation. Assuming you're willing to urgently do this asap.

To make the aforementioned easier to read & view I took it apart into a [JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/dlamblin/0swuwqep/1/).

And here's just the JavaScript inlined into the answer (this is not a gantt chart, it's a vertical layout of scheduled blocks of time over a 7 day week):

```
    var timeFmt = d3.time.format.utc('%H.%M'),
      weekdaydef = 'Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun'.split(' '),
      weekdayseq = 'Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun'.split(' '),
      axes = [null, null, null, null];

    function hm(i) {
      var s = i.toFixed(2);
      return timeFmt.parse((s.length < 4) ? '0' + s : s);
    }
    var timeData = [
        {key: "m1","wday": 0,"begin": hm(6.00),"end": hm(7.00),
        label: "Rising, dress etc\n\retc"},
        {key: "m2","wday": 0,"begin": hm(7.00),"end": hm(7.30),
        label: "Prep Sophie"},
        {key: "m3","wday": 0,"begin": hm(7.30),"end": hm(8.00),
        label: "Transit to School"
      }, {
        key: "t1",
        "wday": 1,
        "begin": hm(6.00),
        "end": hm(7.00),
        label: "Rising, dress etc"
      }, {
        key: "t2",
        "wday": 1,
        "begin": hm(17.00),
        "end": hm(18.00),
        label: "call"
      },

      {
        key: "w1",
        "wday": 2,
        "begin": hm(6.00),
        "end": hm(7.00),
        'color': 0,
        label: "Rising, dress etc"
      }, {
        key: "w2",
        "wday": 2,
        "begin": hm(7.00),
        "end": hm(7.30),
        'color': 0,
        label: "Prep Sophie"
      }, {
        key: "w3",
        "wday": 2,
        "begin": hm(7.30),
        "end": hm(8.00),
        'color': 1,
        label: "Transit to School"
      }, {
        key: "w4",
        "wday": 2,
        "begin": hm(8.00),
        "end": hm(9.00),
        'color': 2,
        label: "Read Emails"
      }, {
        key: "w5",
        "wday": 2,
        "begin": hm(9.00),
        "end": hm(10.00),
        'color': 2,
        label: "Write Emails"
      }, {
        key: "w6",
        "wday": 2,
        "begin": hm(10.00),
        "end": hm(13.00),
        'color': 3,
        label: "Job"
      }, {
        key: "w7",
        "wday": 2,
        "begin": hm(13.00),
        "end": hm(14.00),
        'color': 4,
        label: "Lunch & Meditation"
      }, {
        key: "w8",
        "wday": 2,
        "begin": hm(14.00),
        "end": hm(15.00),
        'color': 5,
        label: "Pick Sophie & Home"
      }, {
        key: "w9",
        "wday": 2,
        "begin": hm(15.00),
        "end": hm(18.00),
        'color': 0,
        label: "Clean"
      }, {
        key: "wa",
        "wday": 2,
        "begin": hm(18.00),
        "end": hm(19.00),
        'color': 0,
        label: "Plan"
      }, {
        key: "wb",
        "wday": 2,
        "begin": hm(19.00),
        "end": hm(20.00),
        'color': 0,
        label: "Wrap: Read Email & Clean"
      },

      {
        key: "r1",
        "wday": 3,
        "begin": hm(6.00),
        "end": hm(7.00),
        label: "Rising, dress etc"
      },

      {
        key: "f1",
        "wday": 4,
        "begin": hm(6.00),
        "end": hm(7.00),
        label: "Rising, dress etc"
      }
    ];
    timeData = timeData.sort(function(a, b) {
      var o = d3.ascending(a.wday, b.wday);
      return o === 0 ? d3.ascending(a.begin, b.begin) : o;
    });
    // Spacing out times by 5 minutes... see display
    // var timeDataMap = d3.map(timeData, function(d) {return d.key;});
    // timeDataMap.forEach(function(k,v) {v.end.setMinutes(v.end.getMinutes()-5);});
    // timeData = timeDataMap.values();
    var scale, colors = d3.scale.category10();
    colors.range(d3.range(10).map(
      function(i) {
        return d3.rgb(colors(i)).brighter(1.25).toString();
      }));

    function d3UpdateScales() {
      var svg = d3.select('#timeblock')[0][0],
        margin = {
          top: 25,
          right: 80,
          bottom: 25,
          left: 80
        },
        width = svg.clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = svg.clientHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
      return scale = {
        margin: margin,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        time: d3.time.scale.utc() // not d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([d3.min(timeData, function(d) {
              return d.begin
            }),
            d3.max(timeData, function(d) {
              return d.end
            })
          ])
          .rangeRound([0, height]),
        days: d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(weekdayseq)
          .rangePoints([0, width]),
        week: d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(weekdayseq)
          .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.05),
      }
    }

    function d3Update() {
      var scale = d3UpdateScales();

      // Update…
      var svg = d3.select('#timeblock');
      if (svg.select('g.view')[0][0] == null) {
        svg.append('g').attr('class', 'view').attr('transform', 'translate(' + scale.margin.left + ',' + scale.margin.top + ')');
      }
      var g = svg.select('g.view').selectAll('g.data')
        .data(timeData);

      // Enter…
      var ge = g.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr('class', 'data');

      ge.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return scale.week(weekdaydef[d.wday]) + (scale.week.rangeBand() / 2)
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          var e = new Date(d.end);
          e.setMinutes(e.getMinutes() - 5);
          return scale.time(d.begin) + ((scale.time(e) - scale.time(d.begin)) / 2)
        })
        .attr("width", 0)
        .attr("height", 0)
        .attr("style", function(d) {
          return ("color" in d) ? "fill:" + colors(d.color) : null
        })
      ge.append("text")
        .attr("dy", "1.1em")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.label;
        });

      // Exit…
      g.exit().remove();

      // Update…
      g.select("rect")
        .transition()
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return scale.week(weekdaydef[d.wday])
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return scale.time(d.begin)
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          return scale.week.rangeBand()
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          var e = new Date(d.end);
          e.setMinutes(e.getMinutes() - 5);
          return (scale.time(e) - scale.time(d.begin))
        })
      g.select("text")
        .transition()
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return scale.week(weekdaydef[d.wday]) + 5
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return scale.time(d.begin)
        });

      axesAddOrUpdate(svg);
    }

    function axesAddOrUpdate(svg) {
      var xaxis_t = d3.svg.axis().scale(scale.week).tickSize(13).orient('top'),
        yaxis_r = d3.svg.axis().scale(scale.time).tickSize(7).orient('right'),
        xaxis_b = d3.svg.axis().scale(scale.week).tickSize(13),
        yaxis_l = d3.svg.axis().scale(scale.time).tickSize(7).orient('left');
      // global axes array contains top, right, bottom, left axis.
      if (null == axes[0]) {
        axes[0] = svg.append("g").attr('class', 'axis')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + String(scale.margin.left) + ',' + String(scale.margin.top) + ')')
          .call(xaxis_t);
      } else {
        axes[0].transition().call(xaxis_t);
      }
      if (null == axes[2]) {
        axes[2] = svg.append("g").attr('class', 'axis')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + String(scale.margin.left) + ',' + String(scale.height + scale.margin.top) + ')')
          .call(xaxis_b);
      } else {
        axes[2].transition().call(xaxis_b);
      }
      if (null == axes[3]) {
        axes[3] = svg.append("g").attr('class', 'axis')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + String(scale.margin.left - 5) + ',' + String(scale.margin.top) + ')')
          .call(yaxis_l);
      } else {
        axes[3].transition().call(yaxis_l);
      }
      if (null == axes[1]) {
        axes[1] = svg.append("g").attr('class', 'axis')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + String(scale.margin.left + scale.width + 5) + ',' + String(scale.margin.top) + ')')
          .call(yaxis_r);
      } else {
        axes[1].transition().call(yaxis_r);
      }
    }

    window.onload = d3Update;

    d3.select('#b_rotate').on("click", function(d, i, t) {
      weekdayseq.push(weekdayseq.shift());
      d3Update();
    });
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks! I'm working on this. In the meantime, would you by any chance know the answer to this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498470/create-d3-js-graph-from-data-on-mongodb-server?noredirect=1#comment62491935_37498470

Comment: @glitterati I don't use MongoDB so I don't know the answer to your question. It's possible someone else made a mapping library already though. I added some links to documentation, and ONE example Gantt chart.