# Loading my simple D3 project in chrome gives me this error. "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED". What can I do to fix it?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, d3.js

I have tried looking it up online and I cannot really find a clear answer. I am trying to load some JSON data from mongoDB so that I can plot it within some D3.js charts and the browser keeps give me this error. Please could someone offer some advice? Am i calling it wrong. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kONR.png)

This is how i call it in the code..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vigE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's interesting to know whether you are getting any data in console for the mentioned URL in d3.json ?

Comment: No I am not getting anything, and i am not sure why exactly. I initially thought access restrictions on the DB but i removed all of them to test and nothing

Comment: can you please try hitting this URL in your browser by this you will get to know whether  the end point is accessible or not.

Comment: sorry i might have misunderstood, but i tried putting it in the search bar it just loaded a load of google pages, not sure i did the right thing

Comment: Are you sure you are able to connect to database using this connection string? 
Also you are directly using mongo db connection in d3 which will not gonna work you have to use a server side technology like node.js , python, or asp.net to connect with mongo db which will give you the data upon API calls.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498470/create-d3-js-graph-from-data-on-mongodb-server

Comment: maybe that is where my issue is, i am only using that. i.e. i am using the d3.json to call the mongoDb with the aim of trying to retrieve data. So what you suggest is using something like node.js or express to connect and retrieve the data? if i did this would i then be able to store the result of the get request and store it in a file so i can then use the d3.json method?

Comment: Yes you are right you can use node.js or express to connect and then an API call will work for you no need to store it in a file just directly pass that response via an ajax call if you want to keep it simple you can use jquery ajax calls(https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp) to trigger, get response and pass it to d3.json

Comment: Amazing I will give that a wiz! thank you so much, greatly appreciated.